# Remove the WHERE clause in SQL statement

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where I want to remove the `WHERE` clause in a SQL query string. For example:

```
Select Name From Table Where ID=@ID
```

Output:

```
Select Name From Table
```

In some case there are SQL with `Group By` and `Order By`

Example:

```
Select Name From Table Where SomeField=@SomeField Group By Name Order By Name
```

Output:

```
Select Name From Table Group By Name Order By Name
```

Comment: Personally, that looks like a very weird requirement to me. [Maybe an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: How about nested queries, multiple joins, multiple `WHERE`s, etc?

Comment: You could always replace `WHERE` with `WHERE 1 = 1 OR`..  but as Uwe says, this is quite a strange requirement.

Comment: I think you need to give more explanation on the problem and why you require such solution (which I feel will not be 100% accurate solution). May be there is another solution for your problem.

Comment: I think you have to add or remove where clause depends on some condition, if so you have to apply that condition before building the query text instead for modifying query after building

Comment: Thanks, I am creating an application that shows all the column, DataFieldType, etc based on the entered query in a `Textbox`. I am using the `GetSchemaTable` to get those columns. But when I enter a query with `Where` condition it will give me an error.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: You can always do grouping and ordering on the `C#` side. Then you end up with only adding and removing `WHERE` in the end of the query

Comment: Are that outputs as an error or expected result?

Comment: the error is: Must declare the scalar variable "@SomeParameter". With that error I am thinking to remove the `Where` condition or any suggestions?

Comment: So its the users responsibility to provide value for the parameter right? Instead of typing a query like `Where ID=@ID` can't they do something like `Where ID=100`

Comment: Do you let users put in any SQL in the textbox? In that case they forgot the declare @SomeParameter. Or perhaps they should not use variables at all, just put in the SQL statement without it.

Comment: What happens if they put in a DROP DATABASE Statement? It seems a little dangerous to let end user write SQL, but that is another issue.

Comment: Question - `What happens if they put in a DROP DATABASE Statement?`  Answer - **Zhyke is in trouble**

Comment: The form I am creating is only accessible to admin role. Anyway, the SQL query they are entering in the `Textbox` will store in database. The output columns will be stored in the database too. I need them because I am creating a Generic code to populate a grid.

Comment: No worries about the DROP, ALTER and CREATE, they were already filtered.

Comment: This might be helpful http://regexr.com/3gcrj

Comment: Do you filter out this too? `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'format c:';`?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I am getting an error `Unrecognized escape sequence`. The code i am using is `strQuery = Regex.Match(strTmpSQL, "/where\s\w+=@\w+/ig").Value`

Comment: @Magnus I tried to enter that in the `Textbox` and an error prompted unrecognized `Select` command. It is also filtered.

Comment: there are \ in the expression you need to negate its meaning. Use `/where\\s\\w+=@\\w+/ig`

Comment: That was bold of you ;-) But ok.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy it returns empty string.

Comment: @Zhyke try `@"/where\s\w+=@\w+"` also you need to do a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy thanks, that works.

Comment: Cool !!  Happy coding.